# Decompressing byte array in java

Tags: java, compression, qr-code

While decompressing adhaar qr code sample data steps follow as given    https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/User_manulal_QR_Code_15032019.pdf, I got `java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check error while decompressing the byte array`

```
// getting aadhaar sample qr code data from

// https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/User_manulal_QR_Code_15032019.pdf

String s ="taking  here Aadhaar sample qr code data";
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s, 10); 

byte[] array = bi.toByteArray();    
Inflater decompresser = new Inflater(true);
decompresser.setInput(array);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new 
ByteArrayOutputStream(array.length);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
while (!decompresser.finished()) {  
    int count = decompresser.inflate(buffer);  
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);  
}  
outputStream.close();  
byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray(); 
String st = new String(output, 0, 255, "ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println("==========="+st);
```

Comment: Please provide code *and data* that reproduces your problem. It's almost a certainty that there is something wrong with your input data.

Comment: You can get input data from https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/User_manulal_QR_Code_15032019.pdf . My concern is while reading the e-aadhaar Qr code , which in base 10 value of secure QR code, While performing validation steps as given in above metniton pdf section (3.2) I got java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check.

Comment: I'm not going to extract data from a PDF. On StackOverflow, you need to post code that can be readily reproduced by the readers. See [mcve]. Otherwise, as you see, you won't get many responses, and you can't expect everyone to spend an hour on getting everything ready to analyse your question.

Comment: @RakeshKumar.how are you able to get the get the Email_mobile_present_bit_indicator_value after  you have achieve the encoded string .can you please share the code for further steps mentioned in the doc. which can help to get the appropriate  fields

Comment: sorry @atish naik , I left that organization where I am working on that code, so no source code with me.

Comment: sorry @atish naik , I left that organization where I am working on that code, so no source code with me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64341259/8362967

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Inflater class of java which uses Zlib compression algorithm. However in UIDAI secure QR code, GZip compression algorithm is being used. So the decompression logic has to be modified as following:-

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(in);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while((len = gis.read(buffer)) != -1){                                        os.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            os.close();
            gis.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        byte[] output = os.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was trying to use a different gunzip method I found around here where they were just returning a readLine from a BufferedReader. While that might work for strings, it DOES NOT work for byte arrays. It was corrupting the data, but your code here works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This is the project which decoded the data Correctly:
https://github.com/dimagi/AadharUID

It supports secure, xml and uid_number type